# Spring Boot Dashboard is not activating automatically in VSCode

Tags: spring-boot, visual-studio-code

On AzureDevOps I choose the option to VSCode but when I open the project in new window, Spring Boot Dashboard is not activated until I open any java file.
Does anybody know why this is happening? I have installed Extension Pack for Java, Maven for Java,
Spring Boot Dashboard, Spring Boot Extension Pack, Spring Boot Tools, Srping Initializer Java Support.

The person who created master branch and pushed to git remote does not have this problem. Only the ones who clone repository encounters this problem of not seeing spring boot dashboard automatically. Please help me find out the reason. Thanks!

Comment: Any solutions to this issue?